# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^ndx\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^n dx\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$$

I was thinking of Holder's inequality for integrals, but I got: $(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^n dx)^{\frac{1}{n}} \ge (\frac{1}{b-a})^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)dx|$ but how to bring equality with supremum?

Comment: It should be $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^n dx\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$

Comment: That holds too, but the original statement is fine.

Comment: Suhail if that could be proved then the original problem can be proved too as we have $(\frac{1}{b-a})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ in the LHS which goes to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Correct, I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $M = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} \lvert f(x) \rvert$. We see $$\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \le \left( \int_a^b M^n dx \right)^{1/n}  = M(b-a)^{1/n}, \,\,\,\,\, \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb N.$$ Sending $n \to \infty$ gives $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \le M.$$ On the other hand, there is some $x^*$ which achieves the supremum so by continuity, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \ge M - \epsilon$ when $x \in (x^* -\delta, x^*+\delta)$ (assuming that $x^*$ is not on the boundary; the proof can easily be adjusted if $x^* =a$ or $x^* = b$). Then we see $$\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \ge \left( \int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \ge \left( \int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} (M-\epsilon)^n dx \right)^{1/n} = (2\delta)^{1/n}(M-\epsilon)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Sending $n\to\infty$ gives $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \ge M-\epsilon.$$ But $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, so we can send it to zero and see $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \ge M.$$ Thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} = M.$$ NOTE: this isn't technically correct. Of course *a priori* we don't actually know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n}$ exists, so the first time we take the limit above, we should really use $\limsup$ and the second time, we should really use $\liminf$. Then we actually proved $$M \le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \le M$$ which of course implies that the limit exists and is $M$.

Comment: Just can you clarify why $$\left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \ge \left( \int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n}$$ ?

Comment: We see \begin{align*} \left( \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} &= \left( \int_a^{x^*-\delta} \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx +  \int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx +  \int_{x^*+\delta}^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n} \\ &\ge \left( \int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \right)^{1/n}  \end{align*} since $$\int_{x^*+\delta}^b \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx , \,\,\,\,\,\int^{x^*-\delta}_a \lvert f(x) \rvert^n dx \ge 0.$$

Comment: Your solution is quite enlightening @User8128...really brilliant. Can you tell me some good sources or books for these problems? I am at precollege level

Comment: Perhaps Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. What specifically are you looking to learn?

Comment: I am specially trying to strengthen my concepts on the epsilon delta definition of limits, and convergence

Comment: A rigorous calculus book or a real analysis book is what you need. I think Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis is good. Note: I made a technical edit to the solution above. It's a somewhat minor point, but important if you want to be fully rigorous.

Comment: Well I may be dumb but can you show me particularly how to handle the case when $N=a$?