# $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}(\int_ {0}^{1}|f(x)|^p)^{1/p}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ if $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on its domain

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, proof-writing, normed-spaces

I have recently been trying to prove the following using only knowledge from chapters 1 through 6 of Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis". In other words, **I cannot use the concept of measure**.

> $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}(\int_ {0}^{1}|f(x)|^p)^{1/p}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ if $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on its domain

where $| \cdot|$ is the absolute value function.
However, I am unsure where to start and most proofs I have found online rely on concepts not covered in the mentioned chapters.

My attempt involved writing $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}(\int_ {0}^{1}|f(x)|^p)^{1/p}$ in the form $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(\frac{i}{n})|^p))$. From there, I tried to use properties of Darboux lower and upper sums and integrals to reach an $\epsilon-\delta $ limit conclusion but I was not able to make much progress.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Any hints, tips, or proof outlines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Prove two direction of inequalities: one direction is easy, and for the other direction, choose small interval s.t $|f(x)|\ge{\rm max}|f(x)|-\varepsilon$.

Comment: You don't need the “concept of measure”, only that $f(z) > M - \epsilon$ on some interval of positive length, which follows from the continuity. Perhaps this one is clearer? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1766241/42969

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059678/42969 and the linked questions – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20(%5Cint%20_a%5Eb%7Cf(x)%7C%5Endx)%5E%5Cfrac%201n%3D%5Cmax%5Climits_%7Bx%5Cin%5Ba%2Cb%5D%7D%7Cf(x)%7C%24)